# Commerce Flat Rate Shipping not being added in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I'm hoping this is straight forward, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I have Drupal Commerce setup and working properly.
I have Commerce shipping setup to use a flat rate of $7.00
I have Commerce PayPal Express checkout setup.

Product is $40.00
Flat Rate shipping is $7.00
Once customer adds shipping the total reflects $47.00
When the customer goes to PayPal to pay, PayPal is only showing $40.00

For some reason, the shipping amount is being removed once the customer hits PayPal.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change the weight of the flat rate on rules? The flat rate weight should be higher than the weight of PayPal Express rule.

Comment: Are you sure that what's happening is a shipping line disappearing and not just customers browsing to Express Checkout directly from the cart page? Did you enable shipping service selection in the order confirmation checkout pane provided by the PayPal Express Checkout module?

Answer (score 0):

> Did you enable shipping service selection in the order confirmation
>   checkout pane provided by the PayPal Express Checkout module? – Ryan
>   Szrama

Thanks again Ryan for pointing out another not so obvious answer!

To "enable shipping service selection in the order confirmation checkout pane provided by the PayPal Express Checkout module"

Go to:
admin/commerce/config/checkout/form/pane/paypal_ec_review

"Checkout pane configuration
These settings are specific to this checkout pane.
Checkout panes to include on the Express Checkout review and confirm page"

Check this box! - Shipping service

Ralph Manis - Infinitee Web Design